# How to disable validating row when it loses focus in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview, and I would like to allow the end user to type whateever he wants in the rows and the validation will be done later programmatically.

### For example

**Column1 :** AllowDBNull = true

The user will still be able skip the cell related to Column1 and move to another row (may be to fill it later)

And the validation will be performed once he clicks ValidateButton.

I have been looking to :

```
DataGridView.CausesValidation = False
```

But that was unsuccessful.

I was trying also

```
DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never
```

but couldn't apply this property to **DataGridView.Datasource**

Here is a bit of my code

```
'CreateMasterDataTable and CreateDetailDataTable are two functions that return two datatables
Master_DT = CreateMasterDataTable()
Detail_DT = CreateDetailDataTable()

DataSet.Tables.Add(Master_DT)
DataSet.Tables.Add(Detail_DT)

DataSet.Relations.Add("Relation", Master_DT.Columns("City"), Detail_DT.Columns("City"))

Master_BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet
Master_BindingSource.DataMember = Master_DT.TableName

Details_BindingSource.DataSource = Master_BindingSource
Details_BindingSource.DataMember = "Relation"

DataGridView.DataSource = Details_BindingSource
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to disable the row validation once it loses focus please ?
Thanks

Comment: validation only occurs when you submit the form on postback. well, after clientside validation. what's wrong with the regexp validators? ;o you can skip the ones you don't want to validate by just returning true. anyways http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I'm on VB.Net. Thanks though.

Comment: ? there's VB code there, but more importantly. read the entire article. also, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your proposal but I couldn't get the answer. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: no sorry, i don't... oh wait, i lied...